# Blanc vbCritical VBA message when ribbon is customized in Excel 2007

Tags: excel, excel-2007, ribbon, vba

I'm developing an Excel-2007/VBA application in which the ribon is customized and do experience a big problem.

In my Robbpn there are 10 button who have attached to them a getVisible callback and one also has a dynamic label (also using a call back) (= a total of 11 callbacks). These all work fine.

Two problems however do appear:

1 not so important but possible related) When a run my macro program having set a breakpoint in VBA then as soon as that breakpoint is and the VBA editor appears I get 11 time an Alert showing the message: Can’t execute code in breakmode.

2 (important error). In my VBA-application i'm doing an sql query using Connection.ODBCConnection.Refresh. This query is slow. After about 10 secondes my window background changes (to light blue) although screenupdating=false. At that moment the first of 11 error alert appears. These alerts do not contain any text only a vbCritical icon an Ok and a Help button. When pressing that OK button (11 times) my program continues completing the refresh and all is fine.

Is there anyway to eliminate these alerts. (by the way an on error does not trap them, nor are the influenced by Application.displayAlerts true or false or screenUpdating true or false).

Anyone has some tips to solve this?
Greating John

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution.  Turn off multi-theading calculation in the Advanced Excel Options for formulas.  I found additional documentation indicating the ribbon callbacks are not thread safe.

Item 1 is the intended behavior when using the ribbon. The second item is not intended, and I have not found a resolution as yet.  In my case, my Ribbon checkboxes will lose their state when this occurs.